Is there a way to convert a recursive Prolog code block into a DFS implementation for a Missionaries and Cannibals problem?
I'm... perhaps trying to learn how to use Prolog. Currently I'm attempting to solve the Missionaries and Cannibals problem - where you need to move 3 missionaries and 3 cannibals across a river and if the cannibals ever outnumber the missionaries, they eat them. A boat can be used to cross the river, and up to two people can use that boat (it needs at least 1 person on it in order to move from one side of the river to the other).
I've been having trouble with it, so I've been looking at solutions online (perhaps not the best idea). Pretty much all of them seem to only generate one solution to the problem, but I was under the impression that there's more than 1 solution. I spoke with a friend about this and he suggested using a DFS implementation, but I don't quite understand how to use it in a way that fits with the states utilized in the Missionaries/Cannibals problem. The solution I was looking at had this recursive solution in Prolog:
path([A,B,C],[D,E,F],Traversed,Moves) :-
   move([A,B,C],[I,J,K],Out),
   legal([I,J,K]),  % Don't use this move unless it's safe.
   not(member([I,J,K],Traversed)),
   path([I,J,K],[D,E,F],[[I,J,K]|Traversed],[ [[I,J,K],[A,B,C],Out] | Moves ]).

Legal is whether or not a move can be made without a missionary being eaten:
legal([B,A,_]) :-
   (A =< B ; B = 0),
   C is 3-A, D is 3-B,
   (C =< D; D = 0).

And move involves each of the rules dictating how the missionaries and cannibals can move.
How can I create a solution that uses DFS to generate all correct answers over recursion which only generates one solution?
I've run the solution code but it doesn't exactly help me understand things too well, and my inexperience with Prolog makes it difficult for me to convert the recursive solution to a DFS one.

Part of the "magic" of Prolog is that a Depth-First-Search mechanism is an intrinsic part of the execution model.  The corresponding search tree is defined implicitly by the nondeterministic language constructs (such as alternative clauses or the semicolon) that are encountered during the execution of your (possibly recursive) code.
So, provided that your code's move-predicate defines several alternative moves, you already have a DFS implementation!  When you run your code, you get a first solution, corresponding to the leftmost successful path in your search tree.  Further solutions are found, on request, via backtracking.  At a Prolog system's top level, this is usually requested by typing a ; (semicolon).
Consider this simplified program
moves([]).
moves([X|Xs]) :- move(X), moves(Xs).

move(a).
move(b).

Here we have two sources of nondeterminism: the choice between empty and nonempty list clause in moves/1, and the choice between a and b in move/1. Depending on circumstances, the system will use these to explore different search trees:
?- moves(Xs).
Xs = []
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more) ;
Xs = [a]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more) ;
Xs = [a, a]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more)
...

?- Xs = [_,_], moves(Xs).
Xs = [a, a]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more) ;
Xs = [a, b]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more) ;
Xs = [b, a]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more) ;
Xs = [b, b]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 4)

